# Weird Characters On gzip Package

Tags: gzip, utf-8

I'm trying to gzip my js files which in **js** folder.

```
gzip -cr js
```

I'm using this command on Terminal but this is result:

```
8�H�Q�YUG�`]{_��a"G9xj�C�!��Y �c�S�ؙ�SY�}���-mU�����w��@f�x��
                                                                         Q)���k������;�Nߪ�7�x�z�[�Y1E ��
�b�ŹV���ز�7�W���k���!�Z���奩�Vi�HC��r�R��Nj�Q�k�SV[XnL=(v٧p'Ҽ�o�E�P)���vkﱮX|-�t�ii��b!�vF�~F��� �|X���*b
3��y�#�s��8k(��L�o�4�7y�NeNָ��а��(�R��+e^�g�5$��.$tD�{ʔ�YcQ�Z+
cx�
   Ӧc�5�-0Um���Qݫ�B���B�.5 ��U0��?N��1�TOC����-�����#�[j�Je9���J�nv��J���r�us����ϸ����~����Ğ�c_'��q�=��J���^    >���d���F������KRV綶�yꮖ�8��O�׶=Qz@���NqI{Ḧ������7yM=
y�N�e��.'K�|�ZJ��1�ᬇL�  ��s
                        H��ش�6y*(k�{|�ఱ�    
.�KyDi���࿒���k�G�LZ��rsR�ϫ�)e�Nj����Id�64����_�R8U�2�'���^��;�  �<Y����ͨm�+���K�]R��ǝ'��p[_I ��t��E���-Z�ٙAQ3��@넁�-�m'�+�b����G���~���
                                                               [u�Pps�Q<�㖈x̓a�m�ܪ�������쒁����**z�*K]L�Nf8A�L��d���5�ݗ����O����_Y��P:��
����o��
        ����q]��V��<�!Kd݅��e� ��*|%���
                                      jJc�'p�w�J��Q,��D��a�e�*#Ɖ��1�4|��+3D�}t��Hh(��^Ϭ�j��$��#��P��\>J5����A��J��jO�¿
```

What do you think, what's the problem ? MAybe UTF8 encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-c`  switch tells gzip to write the compressed files to stdout. So this funny characters you see are just the compressed content of your files.

Use `gzip -r js` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me what's the meaning of `stdout` ?

Comment: `stdout` is the standard output, the output of a command (simplified). `stdin` in the standard input: data that is typed in the terminal or piped through another program (in `cmd | app`, the `stdout` of `cmd` goes in the `stdin` of `app`)